# Why do i always get NULL in php response when i try to send some variable using ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I want to pass some json data from javascript using ajax to php file

I've tried a lot of solutions from internet but none of them is working.

This is my javascript file (a.html):

```
    <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
      <script 
      src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js" 
      </script>
      <script>
        var dataPwm = {dataHeat : 1};
        console.log(dataPwm)

        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "b.php",
          data: {dataHeat : 1},
          //cache: false,
          success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
          }
        });
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

and this is my php file in same directory (b.php):

```
    <?php
        $json_string = $_POST["dataHeat"];
        var_dump(json_decode($json_string));
    ?>
```

i expect the output of 1, but the result is NULL

Comment: try just var_dump($_POST) and see what you get

Comment: You must include jquery lib to before your script code ajax

Comment: sorry @GiangD.MAI, but i already added that lib, i forgot to write on my js code above.

Comment: @GiacomoMasseroniChiaro i only get "array(0) { }", but in success function of ajax, it should be 
array(1) {
  ["dataHeat"]=>
  string(1) "1"
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not include Jquery!
 use this in head and it will work:

```
<script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
      crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
```

you are using jquery for ajax, therefore you should first load it and then use it. it is that simple. other than that your code is completely correct. and you should expect int(1) in console.

Comment: sorry, but i already added that lib, i forgot to write on my js code above.

Comment: you get null in console log?

Comment: no, i get correct result for console.log(response) in ajax but in php i get null

Comment: do you try to open b.php directly?

Comment: yeah.... i have tried to open it in my browser.... oh btw i try this in my php hosting file not in a localhost.

Comment: if you go directly to the yourdomain.com/b.php. there won't be a $_POST["dataHeat"] available! because you are not making a Post request. $_POST is a global variable and when you make a post request to b.php the $_POST will be set with the keys and values that you already defined in a.php. it means you have to start from a.php.

Comment: sorry dude but i am newbie in this kind of topics.... it means that i can't make a request to b.php directly from a.html because i've already hosted it, am i right? but i don't understand about i've to start from a.php (i think it should be a.html not a.php)....

Comment: in your a.html when you set  `data: {dataHeat : 1}` in ajax, it is like you set `$_POST["dataHeat"] = 1;` that is why you have to start from a.html.
if you want b.php to work you can set `$_POST["dataHeat"] = 1` at the top of b.php. but it would be meaningless if you do that!

Comment: the whole purpose of ajax is to pass some data to server and get its results without running the php file directly.

Comment: do you mean that it's actually working but i can't see the result in b.php directly?

Comment: ohh dude.... you're right, i test it to directly store to my database and the value is stored.... thank you dude.... :)

Answer (score 0):

there may be a few problems here

1. If there is an error in the browser console, then the jquery is not include
2. You do not need to use json_decode
3. if you want the result to come here

   console.log (response);

need to do

```
$dataHeat= $_POST["dataHeat"];
echo $dataHeat;
```

Comment: in console.log the result is correct but in php echo $dataHeat, i get nothing

Comment: and how do you check the echo $dataHeat?

Comment: You are checking **echo $datasHeet;** just go to *localhost/b.php*?

Comment: i do not try it in a localhost... i try it in my hosting file in cpanel.... i've already registered to my website and i do a code directly in my cpanel....

Comment: tell me how do you check the data **echo $datasHeet;** ?

Comment: in my b.php file, i write code same as i told in a question code above, and then to check wether it's working or not, i open www.mydomain.com/b.php....